# Subtraction becomes addition?

Tags: php, jquery, subtraction

I'm having a bizarre problem in what should be a very simple calculation. When the `addDomain` checkbox is clicked, the page fires an ajax request to the php backend, where the new subtotal is determined based on the parameters passed. When the checkbox is first checked, everything works as it should (ie, the new sum is returned). If the checkbox is subsequently unchecked, the request is fired again, but returns a sum from an addition somewhere instead of the product of a subtraction.

Here is the code I'm using. It should be pretty straightforward as to what I'm trying to do.

```
case 'domainprices':
    $sub = request_var('s', 0.00);
    $checked = request_var('c', true);
    $price = (float) 10.99;

    if($checked){
        $sub = $sub + $price;
    }else{
        $sub = $sub - $price;
    }
    $res['res'] = $sub;
    echo json_encode($res);
break;

case 'hosting':
$id = request_var('id', '');
switch($id){
    case 'economy':
        $res['body'] = '<div>
            <select name="duration">
                <option value="3">3 years @ $2.99/Mo</option>
                <option value="2">2 years @ $3.99/Mo</option>
                <option value="1">1 year @ $4.99/Mo</option>
                <option value="0">1 month @ $5.99/Mo</option>
            </select><br />
            Add Domain Name: <input type="checkbox" name="addDomain" /><br />
            Subtotal: $<span id="subtotal">107.64</span>
        </div>
        <script>
        $("select[name=duration]").change(function(){
            var duration = $(this).val();
            var checked;
            if($("input[name=addDomain]").is(":checked")){
                checked = true;
            }else{
                checked = false;
            }
            Funcs.ajaxCall("services", "mode=hostingprices&d="+duration, function(data){
                $("#subtotal").html(data.result);
            });
        });
        $("input[name=addDomain]").mousedown(function(){
            var subtotal = $("#subtotal").html();
            var checked;
            if($(this).is(":checked")){
                checked = false;
            }else{
                checked = true;
            }
            Funcs.ajaxCall("services", "mode=domainprices&s="+subtotal+"&c="+checked, function(data){
                $("#subtotal").html(data.res);
            });
        });
        </script>';
        $res['name'] = "Economy Hosting";
        echo json_encode($res);
    break;
}
break;
```

Comment: Check, if `$checked` is what you expect and if `$price > 0`.

Comment: If a checkbox is not checked, it is not submitted, you know this? To change this behaviour, insert a hidden field before the checkbox with the standard value, like 0

Comment: @KingCrunch - according to firebug, the checked variable contains the correct information upon leaving the page, however when `echo`ing the variable that captures it, it shows as true even when it shouldn't be. `$price` also contains the value that is should.

Comment: Maybe send checked as a string instead, so set checked = 'true'; and checked = 'false'; Could be that the true is not playing nice when you try to attach it within a string.

Comment: That's exactly what I ended up having to do. Turns the casting was being destroyed somehow.